# numpy.cross and similiar functions: Do they allocate a new array on every call?

Tags: python, numpy

When I use `numpy.cross`, it will *return* an array with the results. There's no way to compute *into* an existing array. The same holds for other functions.

1. Isn't it extremely inefficient to allocate a new array upon each call?
2. If so, is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: sorry what's stopping you from assigning back to your orig array?

Comment: @EdChum OP's concern is that it takes extra memory (O(N)) to store that intermediate result, and that extra memory may mean extra time.

Comment: @kennytm but I don't see how you can avoid creating the temporaries and returning a new array with the results is safer than trying to overwrite the orig array in place as you'd need some kind of transactional safety if it borks part way through the process which is not designed in

Comment: I do not exactly know what happens internally, so I'm just looking for a good recommendation on how to handle the issue in practice.

Comment: @EdChum: Yes that's why I say "may" ;) But I doubt numpy has any transactional safety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of `np.cross` (as of 1.9) takes great effort to avoid temporary arrays.  Where possible is uses views of the inputs, even when it has to roll the axes.  It creates the output array

```
cp = empty(shape, dtype)
```

and then takes care to perform calculation in-place, using the `out` of `multiply` and `-=` kinds of assignment.

```
multiply(a0, b1, out=cp)
cp -= a1 * b0
```

However most of these operations are still buffered.  That is `a1*b0` writes to a temporary buffer array, which is then subtracted from `cp`.

Usually we don't worry about those temporary arrays.  We let the developers worry about efficiency and reliability.  Handling temporary buffers is compiled code's responsibility, not ours.

The unbuffered `add.at` documentation gives some insight into the use of buffering or not.  This unbuffered `.at` method is used to certain serial operations that the regular buffered versions can't handle.  But it is not meant as a way of speeding up code.

It sounds like you want `np.cross` to take an `out` parameter, thinking that if you can use

```
cp = np.empty(rightsize)
for a,b in zip(A,B):
   np.cross(A,B,out=cp)
   <use cp>
```

it will be a lot faster than

```
for a,b, in zip(A,B):
   cp = np.cross(A,B)
   <use cp>
```

I doubt if that would help.  In the big picture the `cp=np.empty(...)` is a minor time consumer.

But lets do a time test with `np.multiply` which does take an `out`:

```
In [18]: x = np.ones((1000,1000))
In [19]: %%timeit 
    ...: y = np.multiply(x,x)
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 12.4 ms per loop
In [20]: %%timeit y = np.empty(x.shape) 
    ...: np.multiply(x,x, out=y)
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 6.48 ms per loop
```

OK, taking the allocation out of the timing loop does cut the time in half.

But if you are repeatedly calling `np.cross` (or some other function like it), I think you should worry more about the number of repeats than details like array reuse.

```
np.cross(np.ones((N,3)), np.ones((N,3)))
```

is considerably faster than

```
for i in range(N):
    np.cross(np.ones(3), np.ones(3))
```

But it would be easy to make a copy of `np.cross` (it's pure Python), and modify it to take an `out`.  Try it and see if it makes a difference.  As long as you use a correct sized `cp` it should work. You'd have to decide whether to bypass the `shape` and `dtype` checks that preceed the `cp=empty...` line.

Answer (score 2):

There is an overhead with the function `np.cross` as it creates a new NumPy array. You can do `x = np.cross(x, y)` but it will not suppress the overhead.

If you have a program where this is actually a problem (as diagnosed by profiling the program, for instance), you are better off turning to a specific optimization strategy. [Cython](http://cython.org/) and [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) come to mind.

Comment: Changing `np.cross` to accept and use an `out` optional argument does not look too hard. But things would go terribly wrong if the input and output overlapped and I guess that's why it is not in the API.

Comment: @Goyo: It would take exactly one sentence in the doc of the function to mention that `out` may not be or overlap with an input argument... A programmer who is able to look for an `out` argument will also be able to understand that limitation, especially when explicitly specified...

Comment: @Michael It was just a guess, I don't know if numpy devs have any policy about this.

Comment: @Goyo: Just a guess here as well ;-)

Comment: @Goyo @Michael I had a look at `np.cross` source code before replying but did not mention it. The code handles 2 and 3d cases and also the case where the cross product is applying along an axis of a larger array. In any case, I guess that this would be premature optimization. For further discussion, NumPy's developer would need to be contacted.

Comment: `cross` is Python code, right?  Copy it and make changes which you think might save an allocation or two.  Then time it, report back.